# Construct sequences from a dataframe using dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, sequences

I would like to construct sequences of user's purchasing history using dictionaries in Python. I would like these sequences to be ordred by date.

I have 3 columns in my dataframe:

```
users        items         date

1             1            date_1 
1             2            date_2
2             1            date_3
2             3            date_1
4             5            date_2
4             1            date_5
4             3            date_3
```

And the result should be like this :

```
{1: [[1,date_1],[2,date_2]], 2:[[3,date_1],[5,date_2],[1,date_3]], 4:[[5,date_2],[3,date_3][1,date_5]]}
```

My code is :

```
df_sub = df[['uid', 'nid', 'date']] 
dic3 = df_sub.set_index('uid').T.to_dict('list')
```

And my results are :

```
{36864: [258509L, '2014-12-03'], 548873: [502105L, '2015-09-08'], 42327: [492268L, '2015-01-29'], 548873: [370049L, '2015-02-18'], 36864: [258909L, '2016-01-13'] ... }
```

But I would  like to group by users :

```
 {36864: [[258509L, '2014-12-03'],[258909L, '2016-01-13']], 548873: [[502105L, '2015-09-08'],[370049L, '2015-02-18']], 42327: [492268L, '2015-01-29'] }
```

Some help, please!

Comment: So where's your code and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: my code is 
`df_sub = df[['uid', 'nid', 'date']]` 
`dic3 = df_sub.set_index('uid').T.to_dict('list')`

 And my results are : 
 `{36864: [258509L, '2014-12-03'], 548873: [502105L, '2015-09-08'], 42327: [492268L, '2015-01-29'], 30732: [370049L, '2015-02-18'], 34830: [258909L, '2016-01-13'] ... }`
 And I like to group by users

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Than you @jonrsharpe for your advice, it is the first time i ask a question in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, set *users* as the index and perform `groupby` w.r.t that. Then, you could pass a function to sort each group by it's  *date* column and extract it's underlying array part using [`.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html).

Use [`.tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) to get back it's `list` equivalent. This gives you in the required format. Finally, use [`.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to get your final output as a dictionary.

```
fnc = lambda x: x.sort_values('date').values.tolist()
df.set_index('users').groupby(level=0).apply(fnc).to_dict()
```

produces:

```
{1: [[1, 'date_1'], [2, 'date_2']],
 2: [[3, 'date_1'], [1, 'date_3']],
 4: [[5, 'date_2'], [3, 'date_3'], [1, 'date_5']]}
```

Comment: maybe I would return to a closed question but I was wondering how could I change the function to take into account only ids ordered by date in the list without the date.

Comment: like this for example
{1: [1, 2],
 2: [3, 1,],
 4: [5, 3, 1]}