# Python : extracting only the first element on a dictionary of list using functions

Tags: python, function, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

In a previous post I have asked for constructing sequences from a dataframe using dictionaries in Python.

[Construct sequences from a dataframe using dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330030/construct-sequences-from-a-dataframe-using-dictionaries-in-python)

I want to change the function proposed in the answer seleted to have only items in the list without dates.

Having:

```
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 1,], 4: [5, 3, 1]}
```

Instead of :

```
{1: [[1, 'date_1'], [2, 'date_2']],
 2: [[3, 'date_1'], [1, 'date_3']],
 4: [[5, 'date_2'], [3, 'date_3'], [1, 'date_5']]}
```

Changing the function :

```
fnc = lambda x: x.sort_values('date').values.tolist()
df.set_index('users').groupby(level=0).apply(fnc).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the items column in the `lambda` as it's being called on the entire df, you can sub-select from the result so you only get the column of interest in the result:

```
In [249]:
fnc = lambda x: x.sort_values('date')['items'].values.tolist()
df.set_index('users').groupby(level=0).apply(fnc).to_dict()

Out[249]:
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 1], 4: [5, 3, 1]}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code and what you say doesn't work, it works for me so you need to post raw data, code to create the df and the code that fails

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I have written this `fnc = lambda x: x.sort_values('date')[0:2].values.tolist()` . But I have the same results I had before.

Comment: and when I wrote the names of my columns `fnc = lambda x: x.sort_values('date')['id1','id2'].values.tolist()` I had and error  `KeyError: ('id1', 'id2')`

Comment: You need additional brackets around the list of columns

Comment: thank you @EdChum , it was just that I have put also the name of the column I have used as an index, I shouldn't have.

Comment: For future reference it's helpful to post a representative example, ideally a sample of your real data with your code that reproduces your issue, it helps us to help you, glad it all works now

Comment: I will thank you. I am a little bit new in forums :)